# Keyboard dismissal not working on Android

Tags: android, keyboard, dismiss

Code is running and prints out "dismissing keyboard" but keyboard does not dismiss.  View v is just the background view that the buttons and textfield are on top of in the relative layout.  I'm running on a S3 API 18

```
public View v;
public EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.v = (View) findViewById(R.id.backgroundView);
    this.et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
    Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("dismissing keyboard");
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() ,0);
        }
    });
    this.v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("dismissing keyboard");
            //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() ,0);
        }
    });

}





<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<View
    android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"


    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchBox"
    android:text="Search"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/testButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/searchBox"
    android:text="testButton"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

The view you pass should be the edittext.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, View layoutThatContainsEditText) {
    ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
        .hideSoftInputFromWindow(layoutThatContainsEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken()
```

to

```
et.getApplicationWindowToken()
```

Comment: I've changed to the line that you have suggested but it still does not dismiss the keyboard.  Maybe if I add my layout file it may shed some light imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(et.getApplicationWindowToken() ,0);